# Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am following a tutorial to write 2 classes for filtering threads in a forum application.I got this error in line

```
 $threads = Thread::latest()->filter($filters); // in threadscontroller
```

**Error**:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter does not exist.

**ThreadsController** with index method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Thread;
use App\Channel;
use App\Filters\ThreadFilters;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ThreadsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){

        $this->middleware('auth')->only('store','create');

    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Channel $channel,ThreadFilters $filters)  
    {

$threads = Thread::latest()->filter($filters);  

if($channel->exist){
    $threads->where('channel_id',$channel->id);
}

$threads = $threads->get();

return view('threads.index',compact('threads'));


     
    }
```

This is the **abstract class Filters**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

abstract class Filters{

protected $request;
protected $builder;

protected $filters = [];

    public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;



    }

    public function apply($builder){
        $this->builder = $builder;

        foreach($this->getFilters() as $filter=>$value){   //filter by,value yunus mesela.
if(method_exist($this,$filter)){    
    $this->$filter($value);  
}

        }

        return $this->builder;

    }


    public function getFilters(){

        return $this->request->intersect($this->filters); 
    } 

}
```

Here **ThreadFilters.php** which extends filters class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ThreadFilters extends Filters
{
protected $filters =['by'];        

protected function by($username){
    $user = User::where('name',$username)->firstorFail();

    return $this->builder->where('user_id',$user->id);          
}

}
```

If I change latest to all, I get this **error**:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
> Illuminate\Support\Collection::filter() must be callable or null,
> object given, called in

Also can anyone explain me what is $builder doing in those classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`latest()` is a modifier shortcut, equivalent to `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`. All it does is add the `ORDER BY` constraint to the query.

`filter()` is a method on the Collection class. That method does not exist in the query builder, hence the "method not found" error you're receiving.

It does not appear that your filter class should be used with the resulting Collection. Rather, it adds conditionals to your original query. Try implementing it like this:

```
// Remove the filters() method here.
$threads = Thread::latest();  

if ($channel->exist) {
    $threads->where('channel_id', $channel->id);
}

// Pass your query builder instance to the Filters' apply() method.
$filters->apply($threads);

// Perform the query and fetch results.
$threads = $threads->get();
```

Also, for future questions, including the tutorial you're attempting/following can provide beneficial context to those helping you. :)

Comment: I guess there is another problem with getFilters method. Method Illuminate\Http\Request::intersect does not exist.Btw i am following laracasts tutorial

Comment: `Request::intersect()` was removed in L5.5. Try using `only($this->filters)` instead.

Comment: Hi thanks when i try to filter by username with : http://forum.me/threads?by=username   i got  Call to undefined function App\Filters\method_exist()

Answer (score 2):

If you change latest to all, you're getting a Laravel Collection. So you are calling `filter()` on a Collection (`$threads = Thread::all()->filter($filters);`).

If you take a look into the [code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L447), you'll see, that the `where()` method of the array class gets called, which calls PHP's [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method. As you can see, a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) must be given.
But you are passing an Object to the filter method, `$filters`, which is an ThreadFilters-Object -> method injection here:
`public function index(Channel $channel,ThreadFilters $filters) ...`

Your error message answers your question in a great way:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Support\Collection::filter() must be callable or null, **object given**, called in

Comment: Hint: my answer only answers your second error message :)