# Why there is error Builder::query does not exist in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In index function I have query, based on roles and id the query getting change.

Following is script in my controller in index method

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->validate([
        'id' => 'sometimes|nullable|string|max:10',
    ]);


    $networks = [];

    $user   = Auth::user();

    if($user->hasRole('admin')){
        $net = Network::query();
    }

    else if($user->hasRole('distributor')){
        $net = Network::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user){
            $q->whereHas('roles', function($r){
                $r->whereIn('name', ['admin', 'owner']);
            })->where('parent_id', $user->id);
        })->query();
    }

    else if($user->hasRole('agent') || $user->hasRole('owner'))
        $net = Network::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user){
            $q->where('email', $user->email);
        })->query();

    $ids_ordered = null;

    if(isset($data['id']) && $data['id']){
        $ids_ordered = $data['id'];
        $net = $net->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $ids_ordered) desc"))
            ->paginate(3);

    }

    if($user->hasRole('admin') || $user->hasRole('distributor') || $user->hasRole('owner'))
        $ownerView = true;

    else $ownerView = false;

    $net = $net->get();
    if(!empty($net))

    $networks = $net->mapWithKeys(function($network) use ($ownerView, $ids_ordered){

        $coinSold   = $this->userNetworkRepo->getcoinSold($network->owner()->id);
        $allocated  = $this->userNetworkRepo->getAllocatedNez($network->owner()->id);
        $open       = false;

        if($ids_ordered){
            $ids_ordered = explode(',', $ids_ordered);

            if(in_array($network->id, $ids_ordered))
                $open = true;
        }

        $hierarchy = [
            'owner'             => $network->owner(),
            'agents'            => $network->agents(),
            'drawAgents'        => $this->drawAgentTree($network->id, true),
            'ownercoinSold'     => $coinSold,
            'ownerAllocated'    => $allocated,
            'open'              => $open,
        ];

        if ($distributor = $network->distributor()) {
           $hierarchy['distributor'] = $distributor;
        }

        $hierarchy['coinSold'] = [
            'ownerView'     => $ownerView
        ];

        return [$network->name => $hierarchy];

        //return [$network->distributor() ? $network->distributor()->getFullName() : 'no-partner' => $hierarchy];

    });

    if($request->ajax()){
        $view = view('admin.networks.partials.displayNetworkIndex', compact('networks'))->render();
        return response()->json(['html' => utf8_encode($view)],  200, ['Content-type'=> 'application/json; charset=utf-8'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }

    return view('admin.networks.index', compact('networks'));
}
```

But when I access page I am getting following error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::query does not exist.

why this error showing? Where is something wrong with this query?

I have searched about it on google and found some threads but those about `keyBy`.

Comment: Are doing "use Network;" at the top of your file/controller?

Comment: @cmac do you means by `use App\Network;` ?

Comment: Yeah, are you including your model?

Comment: @cmac yes in my controller I am including the model `use App\Network;`

Comment: And you need to do "use DB;" if your gonna use DB, I just now noticed you are.

Comment: @cmac yes it already there

Comment: Nevermind, I think this is your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591360/method-illuminate-database-query-builderfilter-does-not-exist

Comment: The query method your trying to use doesn't exist on the Builder class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call `query()` on `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`. It's happening because you are calling where/wherehas and then calling `query()` on it again.

Just simply update it to :

```
if($user->hasRole('admin')){
        $net = Network::query();
    }

    else if($user->hasRole('distributor')){
        $net = Network::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user){
            $q->whereHas('roles', function($r){
                $r->whereIn('name', ['admin', 'owner']);
            })->where('parent_id', $user->id);
        });
    }

    else if($user->hasRole('agent') || $user->hasRole('owner'))
        $net = Network::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user){
            $q->where('email', $user->email);
        });
```

Further more to debug such issues, you can use `php artisan tinker` and you can fiddle around

Answer (score 0):

When you start the query, you call `query()` statically from the model as you are doing but later on when you add `where` conditions, you don't need to call `query()` on that as it anyway returns the query instance so basically remove your `query()` calls and it will work like so:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->validate([
        'id' => 'sometimes|nullable|string|max:10',
    ]);


    $networks = [];

    $user   = Auth::user();

    if($user->hasRole('admin')){
        $net = Network::query();
    }

    else if($user->hasRole('distributor')){
        $net = Network::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user){
            $q->whereHas('roles', function($r){
                $r->whereIn('name', ['admin', 'owner']);
            })->where('parent_id', $user->id);
        });
    }

    else if($user->hasRole('agent') || $user->hasRole('owner'))
        $net = Network::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user){
            $q->where('email', $user->email);
        });

    $ids_ordered = null;

    if(isset($data['id']) && $data['id']){
        $ids_ordered = $data['id'];
        $net = $net->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $ids_ordered) desc"))
            ->paginate(3);

    }

    if($user->hasRole('admin') || $user->hasRole('distributor') || $user->hasRole('owner'))
        $ownerView = true;

    else $ownerView = false;

    $net = $net->get();
    if(!empty($net))

    $networks = $net->mapWithKeys(function($network) use ($ownerView, $ids_ordered){

        $coinSold   = $this->userNetworkRepo->getcoinSold($network->owner()->id);
        $allocated  = $this->userNetworkRepo->getAllocatedNez($network->owner()->id);
        $open       = false;

        if($ids_ordered){
            $ids_ordered = explode(',', $ids_ordered);

            if(in_array($network->id, $ids_ordered))
                $open = true;
        }

        $hierarchy = [
            'owner'             => $network->owner(),
            'agents'            => $network->agents(),
            'drawAgents'        => $this->drawAgentTree($network->id, true),
            'ownercoinSold'     => $coinSold,
            'ownerAllocated'    => $allocated,
            'open'              => $open,
        ];

        if ($distributor = $network->distributor()) {
           $hierarchy['distributor'] = $distributor;
        }

        $hierarchy['coinSold'] = [
            'ownerView'     => $ownerView
        ];

        return [$network->name => $hierarchy];

        //return [$network->distributor() ? $network->distributor()->getFullName() : 'no-partner' => $hierarchy];

    });

    if($request->ajax()){
        $view = view('admin.networks.partials.displayNetworkIndex', compact('networks'))->render();
        return response()->json(['html' => utf8_encode($view)],  200, ['Content-type'=> 'application/json; charset=utf-8'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }

    return view('admin.networks.index', compact('networks'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method "query" only works when you already called one of get results methods (get, first, all etc.) or it was called statically. Try to use getQuery method instead:

```
if($user->hasRole('admin')){
    $net = Network::query();
}

else if($user->hasRole('distributor')){
    $net = Network::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user){
        $q->whereHas('roles', function($r){
            $r->whereIn('name', ['admin', 'owner']);
        })->where('parent_id', $user->id);
    })->getQuery();
}

else if($user->hasRole('agent') || $user->hasRole('owner'))
$net = Network::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user){
    $q->where('email', $user->email);
})->getQuery();
```